# how to change fancybox width and height redirect one page to another page in same fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I have two pages with different height and width.

I need to change there height and width when redirecting one page to another page.

```
$(".anchPrint").fancybox({
    'width': '32%',
    'height': '23%',
    'autoScale': false,
    'transitionIn': 'none',
    'transitionOut': 'none',
    'type': 'iframe',
    close: function () {
    }
});
```

Comment: what version of fancybox? you may try using the `parent.$.fancybox.resize()` (v1.3.x) method after the content has been loaded (you may need to trigger the method from the iframed page though) assuming that the page has specific dimensions (e.g. the `body` or `html` tags have `width` and `height`)

Comment: BTW, I am not sure if you would rather set the dimensions of each page from the anchor that open them on the parent page